# How do I restore the old Visual Studio text selection behavior?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I recently got moved to another VM while working on a project and this copy of Visual Studio seems to have some weird settings.

It used to be that I could double click on a word to select it and then drag to select more words. Now, all I get is that one word highlighted and I'm not able to drag.

How do I restore the previous, sane behavior? I don't see anything in the text editor options in VS's option window.

Comment: Hard to guess, no VS version I ever used worked that way.  Try Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Drag and drop text editing option.

Comment: Did you test the behaviour in other applications (notepad, word)? Sounds more like OS setting rather than visual studio.